# How much can heat/weather affect a table tennis table?

Tags: equipment, table-tennis, maintenance

I live in Southern California, where the heat can reach up to 100 degrees (F) easily in the summer. I only have room for a table in the garage, and am a little worried about how the heat might affect the table via warping. I've ordered a 18mm table (Joola Tour 1800) - in general will it be okay or might it suffer? If so, would this be a slow process over many years or happen on the first couple of hot days?

The table should be in the storage position most of the time, and back in a corner that shares walls with the house - not in direct sunlight. It's very dry out here, and the coldest it ever gets out here is 40 degrees (F) or so at nights during the winter.

Comment: Update after about a year: the table has been holding up just fine through the summer and last winter. I ended up with an 18mm Joola table and have had zero issues.

Answer (score 2):

There won't be much damage to the table's surface unless it is exposed to direct sunlight. But the change in climate might cause slight damage. Covering the table  with a thick table cover would be the best option. The thicker the table's surface is the better protection it provides....

Hope this helps!!!